# How to write inference rules if we are having two antecedents

Tags: math-mode, stacking-symbols

```
\[ \frac{A \rightarrow f[\overrightarrow{B}]:= \Psi \\ \Phi \in
\langle\Psi\rangle} {A \rightarrow f[\bullet\overrightarrow{B}];\Phi} \]
```

I need to get the two antecedents in two seperate lines.

```
A \rightarrow f[\overrightarrow{B}]:= \Psi

\Phi \in \langle\Psi\rangle
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/5764) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 2):

Although I am unfamiliar with the context, you can use an `array` to brake the "antecedents" into separate lines:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
  \frac{\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
    A \rightarrow f[\overrightarrow{B}]:= \Psi \\
      \Phi \in \langle\Psi\rangle
  \end{array}}{
    A \rightarrow f[\bullet\overrightarrow{B}];\Phi}
\]
\end{document}
```

This will place the object centred vertically around the fraction line. If that is not of concern, you can do everything inside an `array` environment:

```
\[
  \begin{array}{c}
    A \rightarrow f[\overrightarrow{B}]:= \Psi \\
    \Phi \in \langle\Psi\rangle \\
    \hline
    A \rightarrow f[\bullet\overrightarrow{B}];\Phi
  \end{array}
\]
```

There are other packages that also provide inference rule functionality, like [`semantic`](http://ctan.org/pkg/semantic) or [`proofs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/proofs).

Comment: I think you meant the [proofs](http://ctan.org/pkg/proofs) package

Answer (score 2):

I have found the [mathpartir](http://cristal.inria.fr/~remy/latex/) package the easiest to use for typesetting inference rules in this style. The default style is side-by-side antecedents but you can put them on separate lines by putting two line breaks between the antecedents. In this case

```
\[
\inferrule{A \rightarrow f[\overrightarrow{B}]:= \Psi \\
\Phi \in \langle\Psi\rangle}
          {A \rightarrow f[\bullet\overrightarrow{B}];\Phi}
\]
```

which will look like

[image: typeset example]